# Change notification system to SSL.(right now it's blocked when using https in Chrome because using http)

Tags: node.js, curl, https, express

I hava a notification system in my site and I am trying to change it from http to https.

But my app.js is listing to port 8888 now.

Is there a quick way I can modify it? I tried several ways online but not works.

(Right now my curl is something like `http://myipaddress:8888`)

Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

```
    /* CONFIGURATION */

/* Web Server Config */
var _postpath = '/send';
var _listenport = 8888;
var _listenaddr = '0.0.0.0';  //use '0.0.0.0' to listen on all interfaces

/* Slave (sub) Redis Server Config */
var _channelfilter = '*';
var _sub_db_addr = '127.0.0.1';
var _sub_db_passwd_protected = true;
var _sub_db_passwd = 'mypassword';
var _sub_db_port = 6379;  //default redis port is 6379

/* Master (pub) Redis Server Config */
var _pub_db_addr = '127.0.0.1';
var _pub_db_passwd_protected = true;
var _pub_db_passwd = 'mypassword';
var _pub_db_port = 6379;  //default redis port is 6379

/* add pub.auth(_pub_db_passwd) in function to enable password


/* SocketIO Config */
var _loglevel = 1;

/* simple-pub-sub Config */
var _secretkey = "mypassword";


/* SERVER CODE -- DO NOT MODIFY */
redis = require('redis');
express = require('express');
socketio = require('socket.io');
fs = require("fs"),
pub = redis.createClient(_pub_db_port, _pub_db_addr); if (_pub_db_passwd_protected) {  }

sub = redis.createClient(_sub_db_port, _sub_db_addr); if (_sub_db_passwd_protected) { }
sub.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, json) { io.sockets.volatile.emit(channel, JSON.parse(json)); });
sub.psubscribe('*');

app = express.createServer(express.static(__dirname + '/public'),express.bodyParser());
app.listen(_listenport, _listenaddr);
app.post(_postpath, function(req, res){
  if(req.body.secretkey==_secretkey){
    delete req.body.secretkey; pub.publish(req.body.channel, JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(200);
  }
});

io = socketio.listen(app);
io.configure(function () { io.set('log level', _loglevel) });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution.

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/ec2-user/privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/ec2-user/certificate.pem')
};


app = express.createServer(options, express.static(__dirname + '/public'),express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: You can force it with express-force-domain npm package as well.